# remove category archive titles

Tags: wordpress, archive

How do I get it to check for a child category or sub category?

```
function wporg_remove_category_title( $title ) {
        if ( is_category() ) {
            $title = single_cat_title( '', false );
        }
        return $title;
    }
    add_filter( 'remove_the_archive_title', 'wporg_remove_category_title' );
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Please explain...
BTW the "remove_the_archive_title" doesn't exist. Maybe you are looking for [get_the_archive_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_archive_title/) filter

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and this [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You can then update your question with details of what you have tried, the specific issue you are having and your relevant code in a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows the issue so we can understand the problem and be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, because your title seems not to ask the same as the content of your question. But I think I can guide you in a direction.

---

If you use `the_archive_title()` inside of your `archive.php` theme file, it will always display `Archive: Post Type Name`. If you want to get rid of the `Archive:` before the title, you can use:

`single_cat_title();`

This will just display the archiv title.

---

To check if a category has child category you can use the wordpress function `get_term_children()`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_children/

This will give you an array of all term children IDs. So if you want to check if the the category term has children, you can do this with saving the children in an array and check if this array is empty.

```
$children = get_term_children($term_id, $taxonomy);

if( empty( $children ) ) {
    // do something if there are no children
} else {
    // do something if there are children
}
```

Comment: *"I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve..."* Answering questions that are unclear (like this one) is discouraged - see **Answer well-asked questions** [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In cases like this, you can add a comment to the question to ask for more information to clarify the issue.